# Cloning SQL Server Production DB

Tags: sql-server, database, clone, production-environment

So I have a production `DB (DB1)` running on one server `(SERVER1)` which has views that take data from another production DB `(DB2)` on another server `(SERVER2)`.

Which is the best way to clone `DB1` to DEV environment `SERVER1_DEV (DB1_DEV)` and change the connection within the views to the corresponding `DB2_DEV` from the corresnponding `DEV` server `SERVER2_DEV`?

Comment: Can you please show some sample  on what  connection looks like`change the connection within the views`

Comment: Are you using [Linked Servers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188279.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to pull data from Server2?  Do you need help cloning the db?  Or are you just looking for help on updating the views, once cloned?

Comment: @TheGameiswar In the first production Db PROD_Server1.PROD_DB1 I have a view like:

>`create view VIEW1
AS
select fields from PROD_Server2.PROD_DB2.table`

>and when cloning the production DB to DEV_Server1.DEV_DB1, it should look like:

>`create view VIEW1
AS
select fields from DEV_Server2.DEV_DB2.table`

Answer (score 0):

Create [synonyms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx) for remote sources and use them instead of hard-coded links to any server in your views.

Example right from msdn:

> CREATE SYNONYM **MyProduct**
>   
> FOR AdventureWorks2012.Production.Product;
>
> GO
>
> SELECT ProductID, Name
>   FROM **MyProduct**
>   WHERE ProductID < 5;

So you'll need to recreate synonyms only - to make them look at another source.